# Rails puts up a routing error: No route matches [PATCH] "/topics/4/posts"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a an issue when I try to update a post with a summary. In the model portion, every post has one summary.

When I try to update or create a post with a summary in the same form, a routing error appears, the same one:

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/topics/4/posts"

Rails.application.routes.draw do
   resources :advertisements, only: [:index, :show]

  devise_for :users
    resources :users, only: [:update, :show, :index]

  resources :topics do
    resources :posts, except: [:index], controller: 'topics/posts' do
    end
  end

  resources :posts, only: [:index] do
    resources :summaries, only: [:create, :update]
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
    resources :favorites, only: [:create, :destroy]
        post '/up-vote' => 'votes#up_vote', as: :up_vote
        post '/down-vote' => 'votes#down_vote', as: :down_vote
    end
```

Do these routes look correct? If so it could be the controller methods. Posts and Summary are separate models, so accounting for this is a little tricky for me.

## Post Controller

```
  def create
@topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
@post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
@post.topic = @topic 
authorize @post

if @post.save 
  @summary = @post.build_summary(summary_params)
  if @summary.save
      @post.create_vote
    flash[:notice] = "Post was saved."
    redirect_to [@topic, @post]
  else
  flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
  render :new
  end
end
end 

 def update
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @summary = @post.summary
    @post.topic = @topic 
    authorize @post

    if @post.update_attributes(post_params) && @summary.update_attributes(summary_params)
     flash[:notice] = "Post was updated."
     redirect_to [@topic, @post]
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

## Summary Controller

```
class SummariesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @summary = @post.build(summary_params)

        authorize @summary

        def update
            @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
            @summary = @summary.update_attributes(summary_params)
        end

    private

        def summary_params
            params.require(:summary).permit(:body)
        end
  end
```

My routes appear to be a mess because at the moment they're not allowing me to update a post or render any errors after the validation.

## EDIT

Here's the posts form. The summary has a validation, but it isn't checked for here. It's a nested form so I'm a little stuck on how to account for that here.

```
<%= form_for [topic, post], :url => "/topics/#{params[:topic_id]}/posts/#{params[:post_id]}", :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %> 
<% if post.errors.any? %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"
        <h4>There are <%= pluralize(post.errors.count, "error") %>.</h4>
        <ul>
            <% post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>

<%= form_group_tag(post.errors[:title]) do %>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form_control', placeholder: "Enter post title" %>
<% end %>
<%= form_group_tag(post.errors[:body]) do %>
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 8, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post body" %>
<% end %>
    <p>Add a picture</p>
<% if post.image? %>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= image_tag( post.image_url) %>
</div>
  <% end %>
      <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :image %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :image_cache %>
  </div> 
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.fields_for :summary, post.summary do |s| %>   
        <%= s.hidden_field :post_id, :value => post.id %>
        <%= s.label :body, "Summary" %>
        <%= s.text_field :body, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter a 1-2 sentence summary" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

## EDIT

Changed the Title from "PUT" To "PATCH"

Comment: Your error is probably located in view. Show how you render your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the table 
[here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) you will see that you need an id of you post. You should fix link in your template: `/topics/4/posts`

It must be like this: `/topics/4/posts/6`

Comment: Yes! Instead of using :post_id, I should be using :id. Seeing as it's a form partial for posts, I only need to use that.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Grosefaid, you use use `:id` instead of `:post_id`.

If you really have to specify the URL, then you could use `topic_item_path(topic, post)` instead of building it yourself.

Even better, since you are already providing `[topic, post]` to `form_for`, you can just remove the `url` option and form just be generated properly.